# IronPython (ScriptEngine) is not thread safe?

Tags: thread-safety, ironpython

I've met an issue when trying to use multiple `ScriptEngine` instances in parallel, since there's no information saying that a single `ScriptEngine` instance could be used concurrently. Please note "thread-safe" is not enough for me. What I need is the real parallelized execution in multiple threads, so I'm trying to use separated `ScriptEngine` instances in different threads.

Here's code I've used for testing.

```
private const string PythonStandardLibPath = @"C:\python.standard.lib";

private const string Script = @"
import collections
import os";

private static void ExecuteOne(int i)
{
  var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
  engine.SetSearchPaths(new[] { PythonStandardLibPath });

  var scope = engine.CreateScope();

  try
  {
    engine.Execute(Script, scope);

    Console.WriteLine("Executed: " + i);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
  }
}

private static void Main()
{
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    var id = i;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExecuteOne(id) );
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Started");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When I run the application, there's an exception thrown like:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)
   at IronPython.Runtime.WeakRefTracker.ChainCallback(Object callback, Object weakRef)
   at IronPython.Modules.PythonWeakRef.WeakRefHelpers.InitializeWeakRef(Object self, Object target, Object callback)
   at IronPython.Modules.PythonWeakRef.ref..ctor(Object object, Object callback)
   at IronPython.Modules.PythonWeakRef.ref.__new__(CodeContext context, PythonType cls, Object object, Object callback)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`5.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Ast.CallExpression.Invoke2Instruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at IronPython.Runtime.FunctionCaller`2.Call2(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object func, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Method.MethodBinding`1.SelfTarget(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object target, T0 arg0)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Ast.CallExpression.Invoke1Instruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonCallTargets.OriginalCallTarget2(PythonFunction function, Object arg0, Object arg1)
   at IronPython.Runtime.FunctionCaller`2.Call2(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object func, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Method.MethodBinding`1.SelfTarget(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object target, T0 arg0)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Ast.CallExpression.Invoke1Instruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleContext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options, ScriptCode& scriptCode)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromSourceUnit(CodeContext context, SourceUnit sourceCode, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportTopAbsolute(CodeContext context, String name)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.Import(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportStar(CodeContext context, String fullName, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleContext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options, ScriptCode& scriptCode)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromSourceUnit(CodeContext context, SourceUnit sourceCode, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportTopAbsolute(CodeContext context, String name)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute6[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportTop(CodeContext context, String fullName, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.Execute(String expression, ScriptScope scope)
   at CSharpConsole.Program.ExecuteOne(Int32 i) in c:\projects\CSharpConsole\CSharpConsole\Program.cs:line 200
```

The exception might not be the same in each run, but it's always a `List<T>` operation indicates a threading issue. Another exception happens on a background thread after a while. I believe it's a cleaning up task.

```
System.ArgumentException: Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.
   at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.RemoveAt(Int32 index)
   at IronPython.Runtime.WeakRefTracker.RemoveHandlerAt(Int32 index)
   at IronPython.Runtime.WeakRefTracker.RemoveHandler(Object o)
   at IronPython.Modules.PythonWeakRef.ref.Finalize()
```

Is there a good way to make it work besides locking everywhere?

Comment: @JeffMercado No. Please check out the test code above. It only contains two import statements.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @melston The solution is: do not use same engine in multiple threads.